# gmaps v3 get latitude from event.latLng

Tags: google-maps

I have an old gmaps application using V2 and I am trying to update it to v3.

I have a really simple problem, but I can't find a solution yet.

How can I strip the latitude and the longitude from the "event.latLng"?
It is returning a `point()`, but I need only the lat alone and the long for itself.

I cant get this to work.

Answer (score 57):

According to [the API for `MouseEvents`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MouseEvent), `event.latLng` contains a [`LatLng`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng), not a [`Point`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Point). If this is the case then you can use the `lat()` and `lng()` methods to get the values separately. If `event.latLng` is actually a `Point` then you can directly access the coordinates using the `x` and `y` properties (not methods).

What type of listener is creating the event?

---

**Edit:** there's an [example in the tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#EventArguments) of how to do what you want. It looks like you're following this already. Did you remember to include the actual `placeMarker()` function declaration?

```js
function placeMarker(location) {
    var clickedLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location, 
        map: map
    });
    map.setCenter(location);
}
```

Or are you not interested in placing a marker, and just want to get the lat and lng values? In that case, all you need is:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    var myLatLng = event.latLng;
    var lat = myLatLng.lat();
    var lng = myLatLng.lng();
})
```

Comment: hallo ..
iam trying the following 

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, \'click\', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });
i just need to extract the lat and lon from this

Comment: Glad to hear it. Which thing did you need to fix?

Comment: `var lat = myLatLng.lat();` and `var lng = myLatLng.lng();` will not work in v3, i checked..

Comment: @TheRaaaZ i tried that in v3, it works. In my case `results[0].geometry.location.lat();`

Comment: serjas please for this :  Absa Centre, Riebeek Street, Cape Town, South Africa gamp3 is not woking