# Google Maps API Using Waypoint LatLng

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using the following to get an array of waypoints:

```
var waypoints = displayer.getDirections().routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoints;
```

This returns an array of coordinates formatted with parenthesis around it, like (37.09024, -95.71289),(37.09324, -95.71259).

When I try to insert these coordinates as waypoints along a new route, it breaks. Is there something I need to do to parse this array and get the coordinates without the parenthesis around the lat/lng values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since .via_waypoints returns a LatLng coordinate, converting it into a string gives it parenthesis.

The only way I can find around this is to use a regex to strip out the parenthesis surrounding the coordinates after joining the array into a string.

I add to the string every time a new waypoint is created, then update a hidden input for waypoint coordinates.

The data is then saved to a database, and when the map loads again, I pull the string of coordinates, split them back into an array, and parse them as waypoint values for my map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lat() and lng() methods, for example like so:

let latitude = event.latLng.lat();

See this answer for details. [gmaps v3 get latitude from event.latLng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875992/gmaps-v3-get-latitude-from-event-latlng)